# How many Facebook ad groups can be created in a given period of time?

Tags: facebook, api, adgroup

I'm receiving more and more often the following error message from Facebook:

**1487225** - The number of adgroups you can create in a given period of time has a limit determined by your daily spend level.  Higher spend levels allow creation of more adgroups.  Increase your daily spend limit or create fewer ads per time period.

I've looked in the [API documentation for errors reference](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/error-reference/) and on [the page that specifically talks about the ad groups](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/adgroup/), but I haven't found a hint about how to identify a way to prevent or at least give dispositions when this error occurs.

I've seen some questions about adgroups around, but none connected to this specific topic.

What is the number/formula to know how many ad groups can be created in a given period of time?

Comment: I think this is deliberately undocumented to stop people assuming the values won't change, just back off and make the rest of the creates later - you should already have a backoff and retry logic for other rate limit issues, so you can use that here - if you hit this limit you're probably doing something wrong, as the limits are such that if you hit the limit, you've probably created so many ads relative to the account's budget that not many of them will get delivered, or each will get a very small amount of delivery

Comment: @lgy I had my suspects about their will to arbitrary change the limit. My problem lies on the fact that I can check how many ads have been published through my application, I have no clue about how many have been published by Facebook platform directly and I cannot make many assumption this way.
That is why I would find very useful a hint on this topic.

Comment: Only the ads created by your app count towards those limits as far as i know, no?

Comment: If the limit is calculated on a daily basis than it is rather unlikely, if it isn't then may be true that they doesn't count towards. Again, this are hypothesis I cannot confirm neither deny.